# WordPress theme options error

Tags: php, wp-query, theme-options

I am building a theme and I need to call theme options 
But I do get errors like white screen and 500 internal server error when I call theme options here

In WP query (newbie in PHP)

```
 <?query_posts ('meta_key=post_views_count&orderby=meta_value_num&order=DESC&meta_value=get_option(mytheme_value);');?>
```

Also in my front end form

```
// ADD THE FORM INPUT TO $new_post ARRAY
$new_post = array(
'post_title'    =>  $title,
'post_content'  =>  $description,
'post_category' =>  array($_POST['cat']),  // Usable for custom  taxonomies too
'tags_input'    =>  array($tags),
'post_status'   =>  'get_option(mytheme_status)',
```

and how can I call a option in functions.php

Comment: what errors are you getting?

Comment: White screen  and some times 500 internal server erroe

Comment: _"AND CAN I CALL A OPTION IN FUNCTIONS.PHP"_ ... Why are you screaming? And why did you add the [tag:php] tag? Nearly every question is PHP related. Please rework your question. Thanks.

Comment: Oops that was a mistake.  I didn't notice it as i had posted this question from my mobile

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, change your code into the following:

```
$value = get_option( 'mytheme_value' );
query_posts ( "meta_key=post_views_count&orderby=meta_value_num&order=DESC&meta_value={$value}");
```

When you use single quotation marks, php isn't parsed in the string, and functions (like `get_option`) will never be called from within a string. Therefore, call the function `get_option` first, and put the value in a double quoted string (which parses variables during execution).

Then change your other code into the following:

```
// ADD THE FORM INPUT TO $new_post ARRAY
$new_post = array(
'post_title'    =>  $title,
'post_content'  =>  $description,
'post_category' =>  array($_POST['cat']),  // Usable for custom  taxonomies too
'tags_input'    =>  array($tags),
'post_status'   =>  get_option( 'mytheme_status' ),
```

When you want to call a function inside an array, using whatever it returnes as value, you don't need to put the function inside single quotes.

Furthermore, if you want to get option values in `functions.php`, you can simply use the following line:

```
$mytheme_status = get_option( 'mytheme_status' );
```

When you still encountering errors after these modifications, and you still get a blank screen, try to find out whats going wrong by looking in your error logs. On a linux environment, the default apache error log file location is `/var/log/apache2/error.log` or `/var/log/httpd/error_log`.

Answer (score 2):

In both codes, the get_option function should be outside of the string, like this:

```
<?php 
$theme_value = get_option('mytheme_value');
query_posts ('meta_key=post_views_count&orderby=meta_value_num&order=DESC&meta_value='.$theme_value);?>
```

and

```
$theme_status = get_option('mytheme_status');
// ADD THE FORM INPUT TO $new_post ARRAY
$new_post = array(
    'post_title'    =>  $title,
    'post_content'  =>  $description,
    'post_category' =>  array($_POST['cat']),  // Usable for custom  taxonomies too
    'tags_input'    =>  array($tags),
    'post_status'   =>  $theme_status,
```

And why do you end this last code with a comma?
You just put a part of the code? If not, you have to remove the comma and close the array.

Also, what are these variables mytheme_value and mytheme_status? Do they exist?

If you still have errors, you should write here the rest of the code.

Comment: They exists  i had just used to make the question proper so all users can understand it